# Simple way to implement parallax effect on my specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm looking all over the web for tutorials and stuff, but I can't get anything to work or a tutorial on just what I want, I'm not very familiar with javascript.

I want the parallax effect on the background of about-banner:

HTML:

```
<div class="about-banner">
    <div class="container">
        (Content doesn't really matter)
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.about-banner {
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url(../images/about-banner.jpg);
    border-top: 20px solid #52cbf5;
    margin: 80px 0 0;
}
```

So simple instructions on how to implement it please!

Answer (score 0):

I created a function for that, it's not flawless but you can toy with the logic:

```
jQuery.fn.parallax = function(strength, multiplier) {
    if (typeof multiplier == 'undefined') multiplier = 1;
    var offset = parseInt($(this).data('offset'));
    var split = $(this).data('offset').split(/([^0-9])/);
    var unit = split[split.length - 2];
    if (!offset) offset = 0;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(this).offset().top) {
        var newVal = (($(window).scrollTop() * strength / 2000 + offset) * multiplier).toFixed(2);
        $(this).css('background-position', 'center ' + newVal + unit);
        console.log($(this).attr('id') + ' ' + 'center ' + newVal + unit);
    }
}
```

In order to use it, you do something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.about-banner').parallax(100, 2);
});
```

You can add a `data-offset="10px"` or something similar if you want it to start at something other than the top.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?